# Django inline formset not saving default values

Tags: python, django, django-forms, inline-formset

I have a child inlineformset that saves if it has been changed by the user, but does not save the default value if left unchanged.

*SeVsEff* is the child, and *patient* is the parent

models.py

```
class Patient(TimeStampedModel):
    patient_id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False
    )
    name = models.CharField("Patient Name", max_length=255)

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )

class SeVsEff(TimeStampedModel):
    value = models.IntegerField(default=20)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py

```
class PatientForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ["name"]

SevseffFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Patient,
    SeVsEff,
    fields=("value",),
    widgets={'value': RangeInput()},
    extra=0,
    min_num=1,
    validate_min=True,
    labels=None,
)
```

views.py

```
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = PatientForm(data=self.request.POST)
        sevseff_formset = SevseffFormSet(data=self.request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            patient_instance = form.save()
            patient_instance.user = self.request.user
            patient_instance.save()

            if sevseff_formset.is_valid():
                sevseff_name = sevseff_formset.save(commit=False)
                for sevseff in sevseff_name:
                    sevseff.patient = patient_instance
                    sevseff.save()
```

So I think the issues is that the sevseff_formset is not registered as valid unless it is changed, but if I add something like:

```
            if not sevseff_formset.has_changed():
                sevseff_name = sevseff_formset.save(commit=False)
                for sevseff in sevseff_name:
                    sevseff.patient = patient_instance
                    sevseff.save()
```

This doesn't work as sevseff_name is empty.

Comment: Do you get an error? What is the value of SeVsEff.value when you save an instance? Also, did you run python manage.py migrate?

Comment: @marke If I don’t move the slider I get an error as a later function is not able to access the value of SeVsEff because it does not exist. If I move the slider the value of SeVsEff is the integer that the slider was moved to and there is no error. Yes I have run migrate

Comment: Could you show the message of the error and where exactly it occurs?

Comment: Sure - the error is 'list index out of range' as the later function is trying to index an empty list. The list is empty because SeVsEff has not been saved to the database. I could easily fix the error by just not trying to access SeVsEff - but that is not going to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does it:

```
sevseff_name = sevseff_formset.save(commit=False)
for sevseff in sevseff_name:
    sevseff.patient = patient_instance
    sevseff.save()
if not sevseff_name:
    SeVsEff(value=20, patient=patient_instance).save()
```

Solution from https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/django-inline-formset-not-saving-default-values/10647/3